# How can I set an element over Twitter's Bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, overlay, modal-dialog, z-index

This is my base HTML for the Twitter's Bootstrap modal:

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="form-horizontal updater" data-type="undefined" data-id="undefined">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="modalLabel">Edit Content</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <strong>Save Changes</strong>
            </button>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As my Firebug says, the `modal` class has: `z-index: 1050`. I was trying to add an element like this:

```
<div class="width: 1000px height: 200px; background: #f00; z-index: 9999;">hi there</div>
```

Into the:

```
<div class="modal-body"></div>
```

But it doesn't work.

So, how can I set an element over all these Bootstrap components?

Answer (score 4):

You have given inline style for class attribute `<div class="width: 1000px height: 200px; background: #f00; z-index: 9999;">hi there</div>`. Try Changing attribute `class` to `style`.

Comment: also you have missed putting `;` after `width: 1000px`.

Comment: you want the modalbox width also resize according to the content?. adding `position:absolute` will make it above all elements but modal box width will remain the same

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `position:fixed` in css of the div that you want on top of the modal and `<style> .modal{z-index:4} </style>` in your code. Hope this helps.

Or else, you can load a modal on top of another modal you can refer to this example as well [Modal on top of Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41159276/7165943).

Or finally you can do one thing, you can hide the modal by using jquery or js (this is what I did) by `$("#myModal").hide()` and `$("#yourdiv").show()`, this resolve the whole z-index problem altogether.