# Opening modal from within a modal, backdrop z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to be able to open a modal within another modal (while the first modal stays open). Here's an example of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2coz893/2/

When you open the second modal, you'll notice that the backdrop/background of the second modal doesn't cover the first modal (i.e. the first modal can still clearly be seen when the second modal is open). This seems to be because the `z-index` of the second modal's backdrop is the same as the other and therefore the first modal is still visible.

How can I prevent this? How can I have the second modal's backdrop cover the first modal?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch first modal
</button>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">first</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Launch second modal
</button>
<p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">second</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Do you expect to have a dark background once second one is open?

Comment: can you show us your problem

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi Yes, I expect the background to be dark if the second modal is opened over the first one.

Comment: So just you need to change the background of modal to transparent black, nothing is gonna change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overriding default Bootstrap's css for more than one modals will fix your problem.

**Method #01:**

Following css will work in case you have only 2 modals.

```
.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 1040;
}
.modal + .modal {
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.modal + .modal {
  z-index: 1060;
}

.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch first modal
</button>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">first</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Launch second modal
</button>
<p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p><p>
Something
</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">second</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Method #02:**

However if there are many nested modals, you can use the following trick:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch first modal
</button>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">first</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
          Launch second modal
        </button>
        <p>
          Something
        </p><p>
        Something
        </p><p>
        Something
        </p><p>
        Something
        </p><p>
        Something
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">second</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Works great!! However, in my own case, I had 3 modals. So to toggle between the multiple modals on click of any previous button. I simply attached a class to each and changed their z-index values based on the order I'm opening them... like .modal.first { z-index: 9999 }, .modal.second { z-index: 9998 }... Then used the snippet for .modal-backdrop and .modal as used above

Answer (score 8):

Fixed it for you :) http://jsfiddle.net/cqLex5ga/4/

```
#myModal2 {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Comment: That just adds another layer of blackness on top of already 2 layers of backdrop.

Comment: You just wanted a visual effect, the functionality is correct still as clicking outside the child modal still closes it, so the functionality still remains, but the UX is correct this way.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is

```
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important; 
}
.modal-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @user1389637 has already answered your question, I would like to suggest you to use some jQuery events to on/off the opacity of the previous modals. You can also use these events for other purposes.

```
$("#myModal2").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal").css("opacity", "0.5");
});

$("#myModal2").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/130zrs9L/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work , if your HTML is going to stay the same. 
http://jsfiddle.net/k2coz893/5/

```
.modal + .modal {
  z-index:1050;
}
.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop{
  z-index:1045;
}
```

Or you can add new classes to new modal to achieve the same